# How do I create an array of references to a class , and store the reference-to values for several other objects in array?

Tags: java, arrays, class, reference, abstract-class

For example, I have this code with these classes. How do i Create an array of references to a class , and store the reference-to values for several other objects like a1 or a2 if created?

```
    public abstract class Test1 {
    // Instance field vars

    public Test(){
    //initializations
    }

    public void method1(){
    //do's
    }

    @override
    public String toString(){
    return (string content)
    }
}
```

then I have another similar class

```
    public class Test2 extends Test1 {
    // Instance field vars

    public Test2(){
    //initializations
    }

    public void method2(){
    //do's
     super.method1();
    }

    @override
    public String toString(){
    return super.toString+(string content)
    }
    }
```

then, my main is something like this

```
        Test1 a1 = new Test2()
    System.out.println(a1.toString());
    a1.method1();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing should stop you using `ArrayList<Test1>`.

```
List<Test1> myArr = new ArrayList<>();
myArr.add(new Test2());
myArr.get(0);
```

Or,

```
 Test1 a1[] = new Test2[10];
   a1[0] = new Test2();
```

Learn about [inheritance](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html) to understand super class and subclass relationship.

Comment: Thanks, I will try array list

Comment: I already know about inheritance and know what super class is. Thanks anyhow

Comment: uhh then it is ok. sorry about that ;)

Answer (score 1):

How about this: -

```
Test1 [] arrayOfReferences = new Test1[10];
```

This can store the 10 references of type `Test1` and you can populate the array with all of the concrete implementations of `abstract class Test1` like `new Test2()`

Comment: Oh so it was as simple as that. Thanks. I thought arrays could only hold variables, I didn't think it'd be so simple.

Comment: No Problem. Just to add to this you might be interested in reading about runtime polymorphism in java.